# Passing a value to Component inside a ngContent

Tags: angular

I'm trying to pass a value from a parent component (MainComponent) to a child component (ChildComponent), but the child component is not declared in the parent template instead it is loaded inside a ngContent from the parent's parent component (the AppComponent).

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<div>' + 
  '<main-component><child-component [big]="big"></child-component></main-    component>' + 
  '<main-component><childuo-component [small]="big"></childuo-component></main-component>' + 
  '</div>'
})
export class AppComponent { }

@Component({
  selector: 'main-component',
  template: '<div><div>{{big | lowercase}}</div><div><ng-content></ng-content></div>'
})
export class MainComponent { 
  big: string = "BIG";
}

@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  template: '<div>Finally: {{big}}</div>'
})
export class ChildComponent { 
  @Input() big: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'childuo-component',
  template: '<div>Second?: {{small}}</div>'
})
export class ChildDuoComponent { 
  @Input() small: string;
}
```

I created a plunker to show my question: [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/NTMuu9t7YtP5Wb2fWCSe?p=preview).

I updated my question to include more details how I expect to allow MainComponent to hold different child components and declare it in a top component (AppComponent).

Answer (score 1):

you don't have `big` as a variable defined in `AppComponent` hence you are not seeing the value.

Notice single quote around `"'big'"`.

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<main-component>
     <child-component [big]="'big'"></child-component>
     <child-component [big]="someVar"></child-component>
  </main-component>`
 })
 export class AppComponent {
   someVar = 'someVar';
 }
```

Here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tDX47Ry5e5D3Sr3uJjfh?p=preview)

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I'm trying to get the variable big from MainComponent to pass it to ChildComponent.

Comment: That is how `ng-content` works, it takes the binding from where the actual HTML is defined, in your case in `AppComponent`, if you want to pass some variable from main to child, you may define child component directly in `main-component`. Cheers!

Comment: And is there a way to define a model where I could insert different ChildComponents to MainComponent in several AppComponent?

Comment: Can you please add more details on what you are trying to achieve? may be a new question.

Comment: Let me modify my question and sample app.

Comment: you can not bind value from MainComponent to the childComponent inside ng-content, if you want to pass values between components you may use services.